# React Component not connected to Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want my navigation component to listen to the redux store so I can change the Login Button to a Logout button when a user is logged in, but the Navigation component doesn't have access to the state

I'm new to React, please let me know if I need to provide more information

In app.jsx I have:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <IndexRoute component={Menu}/>
        <Route path="about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="item/:id" component={Item}/>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

In Main, I render the children and Navigation as such:

```
var Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation/>
      <div className="container">
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In all my components, I have access to my redux store/state via this.props, except in navigation.

When I log this.props in Navigation component I get:

```
 Object {dispatch: function}
```

But in Menu component I get:

```
Object {history: Object, location: Object, params: Object, route: Object, routeParams: Object…}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I guess your store is wrong. store = createStore(rootReducer)? And forget to connect component ?**

Comment: wow, hahah. My store was right and I had it connected but I didn't pass state through connect. I thought it had to something with not rendering Navigation as child. Thanks for catching my silly mistake